# Why does my deploy1Node task fails complaining about java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.nio.fs.UnixPath cannot be cast to java.lang.String?

Tags: gradle, corda

I have a working corda gradle build. Our `deploy1Node` task works properly via IntelliJ, via cmd in Windows and via iTerm in MacOS.

We're using *corda-3.2 open-source* ( `net.corda:corda-3.2:...` ) for this particular build.
The problem occurs with 3.3 open-source as well, and 
Oracle java version "1.8.0_171" on ubuntu, Oracle java version "1.8.0_152" on mac.

When I try to execute it in a Linux box, I receive the following error

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.nio.fs.UnixPath cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

as shown in the stack trace excerpt below:

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':deploy1Node'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:63)
...
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: sun.nio.fs.UnixPath cannot be cast to java.lang.String
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper.generateWhitelist(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:323)
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper.bootstrap(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:85)
        at net.corda.plugins.Baseform.bootstrapNetwork(Baseform.kt:160)
        at net.corda.plugins.Cordform.build(Cordform.kt:66)
...
...
```

How to make this task work regardless of platform ?

the open source jar version is :

```
Corda-Revision: 5ae8325980ad22df8146b983afeaca344fc03c3e
Corda-Vendor: Corda Open Source
Corda-Release-Version: 3.2-corda
```

The enterprise version seems to be ok:

```
Corda-Revision: c9b23a4400923a5cfe88271ce2fedd75740eac40
Corda-Vendor: Corda Enterprise Edition
Corda-Release-Version: 3.1
```

Trying to track down this problem, I've found that in the enterprise version
it displays in the gradle build:

```
> Task :deploy1Node
Putting task artifact state for task ':deploy1Node' into context took 0.0 secs.
Executing task ':deploy1Node' (up-to-date check took 0.0 secs) due to:
  Task has not declared any outputs.
Running Cordform task
Deleting ./build/nodes
Bootstrapping local test network in /mnt/builds/Cordapp/appname/build/nodes
Generating node directory for Node
Copying CorDapp JARs into node directories
```

and in the open source version, the output is:

```
> Task :deploy1Node
Putting task artifact state for task ':deploy1Node' into context took 0.0 secs.
Executing task ':deploy1Node' (up-to-date check took 0.0 secs) due to:
  Task has not declared any outputs.
Running Cordform task
Deleting ./build/nodes
Bootstrapping local network in /mnt/builds/Cordapp/appname/build/nodes
Node config files found in the root directory - generating node directories
Generating directory for Node_node
Nodes found in the following sub-directories: [Node_node]
```

It seems a `_node` is being appended where it should not.

There is another reference of this problem, in a russian site:
http://qaru.site/questions/16922067/why-does-my-deploy1node-task-fails-complaining-about-javalangclasscastexception-sunniofsunixpath-cannot-be-cast-to-javalangstring

Comment: What is your Java version?

Comment: `Oracle java version "1.8.0_171"` on ubuntu, `Oracle java version "1.8.0_152"` on mac

Comment: the open source jar version is : `Corda-Revision: 5ae8325980ad22df8146b983afeaca344fc03c3e`

Comment: @Joel, could you please give us some pointers ? I have updated my question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing the solution, and answering my own question, to prevent this problem, make sure your  `ext.corda_release_group`, `ext.corda_release_version` and `ext.corda_gradle_plugins_version` are
defined *once* and *only once* in any `buildscript` session(s) your
project happens to have.

The problem was caused by trying to get the `build.gradle` to choose between 
2 different corda distributions (open source and enterprise) -- and to change from the *default* choice after it was first used. For `open source`, the `build.gradle`'s  `buildscript` section must have the settings like:

```
buildscript {
...
            ext.corda_release_group = 'net.corda'
            ext.corda_release_version = '3.2-corda'
            ext.corda_gradle_plugins_version = '3.0.9'
            ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.50'
...
```

likewise, for the enterprise version, the settings have to be like:

```
buildscript {
...
            ext.corda_release_group = 'com.r3.corda'
            ext.corda_release_version = '3.1'
            ext.corda_gradle_plugins_version = '4.0.25'
            ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.50'
...
```

Once selected, the references became entangled, and the `deploy1Node` task failed in the open-source version.

One possibility is to use something like:

```
buildscript {
   ...
   ext.profile_name = "open-source"
    switch(profile_name) {
        case ~/enterprise/ :
            ext.cdb_node_location = 'nodes-enterprise'
            ext.corda_release_group = 'com.r3.corda'
            ext.corda_release_version = '3.1'
            ext.corda_gradle_plugins_version = '4.0.25'
            ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.50'
            break;
        case ~/open-source/ :
            ext.cdb_node_location = 'nodes'
            ext.corda_release_group = 'net.corda'
            ext.corda_release_version = '3.2-corda'
            ext.corda_gradle_plugins_version = '3.0.9'
            ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.50'
            break;
        default :
            ext.cdb_node_location = 'nodes'
            ext.corda_release_group = 'net.corda'
            ext.corda_release_version = '3.2-corda'
            ext.corda_gradle_plugins_version = '3.0.9'
            ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.50'
            break;
        break;
    }
```